# Signing and Uploading to Developer Console Error: Upload a signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, publish, developer-console

I am getting this error when trying to upload an update for my app.

I have changed my pc after releasing the previous update, so I had to reinstall Android Studio and everything with it.

Luckily I managed to recover my key.jks file that it's mandatory to update the app since it has to be unique.

I have signed the app from android studio using it, with the alias I remembered and it seems to have compiled and built the app without any problem (I only had to change the keystone and alias passwords).

Still when I try to upload the apk, I get an error in the developer console that says that the apk is not signed.

Any Idea on why this happens?

Comment: same problem :-(